# Word or phrase for behaviors that happen for a while,go away, and come back?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm look for a word or phrase to describe patterns of behavior that happen for a while, go away for some time, and then happen again. No particular pattern with the phases.

Comment: "Intermittent" comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on context, but **[intermittent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intermittent)** is a good possibility here.

> intermittent:
>
> occurring at irregular intervals; not continuous or
>   steady.

Examples of usage would be:

- The patient was having intermittent pains in his side.
- The forecast is for intermittent rain.

**[sporadic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sporadic)** also works in this context.

> sporadic:
>
> occurring occasionally, singly, or in irregular or random instances

- sporadic loud noises kept startling everyone

Comment: also **recurring**: Arthritis causes a recurring pain in my joints.

Comment: Or simply "occasional", of which the definition given by my dictionary reads: "occurring, appearing, or done infrequently and irregularly".